# TCP packet injection with python (scapy) in the mid-stream

Tags: python, tcp, scapy

I've been running in the circles with the following scenario:

A client sends GET request, requesting resource of the size of a few full MSS 1460 bytes TCP packets, let's say 6.
How to force scapy to send a TCP segment with a FIN flag BEFORE all packets are delivered by the server ie. after packet 1,2,3,4,5

Was trying the combination of simple curl requests/loop and a python/scapy script:

```
    from scapy.all import * from time import sleep

    os.system("iptables -I OUTPUT -p tcp --tcp-flags ALL RST,ACK -j DROP")  
    os.system("iptables -I OUTPUT -p tcp --tcp-flags ALL RST -j DROP")

    def packet(pkt):
    if pkt[TCP].flags == 16:
    print('ACK packet detected port : ' + str(pkt[TCP].sport) + ' from IP Src   : ' + pkt[IP].src)
    send(IP(dst=pkt[IP].src, src=pkt[IP].dst)/TCP(dport=pkt[TCP].sport, sport=pkt[TCP].dport,ack=pkt[TCP].seq + 1, flags='F')) sniff(iface="ens160", prn=packet, filter="host 1.1.1.1",count=10)
```

But segment containing FIN flag arrives always late and out of TCP seq/ack sync.